# Why do I receive the error "'train' and 'class' have different lengths"?

Tags: r, knn

I have [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PG1C.png) table:

```
X10$Marital <- as.factor(X10$Marital)
X10$AgeZ <- scale(X10$Age, center = TRUE, scale = TRUE)
X10$IncomeZ <- scale(X10$Income, center = TRUE, scale = TRUE)
X10$Risk <- as.factor(X10$Risk)
```

I then created test and train datasets and classification

```
Test10 <- subset(X10[10, c(2,5,6)]) 
Train10 <- subset(X10[1:9,c(2,4,5,6)])
trueclass <- factor(X10$Risk)
```

I keep getting this error: `'train' and 'class' have different lengths`

I did look another question which suggested that it could be because the classification is not a vector, so I created a vector with these nine values:

```
trueclass <- c("Bad Loss",  "Bad Loss",  "Bad Loss",  "Bad Loss", "Bad Loss",  "Good risk", "Good risk", "Good risk", "Good risk")
```

I still get the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

```
> dim(Train10)
9 4
> 
> dim(Test10)
> 1 3
>
> length(trueclass)
> 9
```

Answer (score 0):

To use knn you should have normalized data. In your case you can only use AgeZ & IncomeZ to predict the Risk in train & test dataframe.

Actually, Test & Train must have the same dimension(cols). You can try the code belows :

```
Test10 <- subset(X10[10, c("AgeZ","IncomeZ")])
Train10 <- subset(X10[1:9,c("AgeZ","IncomeZ")])

trueclass <- as.factor(X10[1:9,"Risk"])

knn <- class::knn(Train10,Test10,trueclass)

knn 
[1] Good risk
```

Hope this will helps

Gottavianoni